# Mvc 3 Image Upload Gallery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image-uploading

I have implemented a file upload for images using **ASP.NET Mvc 3** and the **Microsoft.Web.Helpers NuGet package**. The implementation is quit simple as it allows you to browse for a file and upload it to a specified directory.

Here is what I have for my image upload solution using **ASP.NET MVC 3** and the Microsoft.Web.Helpers **NuGet** plugin.

[image]

Now the **ViewModel** code

```
 namespace MvcImageUpload.Models {
    public class ImageUploadViewModel {
        [UIHint("UploadedImage")]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string ImageAltText { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Now for the **controller** I've simply dropped this into the Home controller, since this is just a mock project to get it working. I just added an `ActionResult` which takes an ImageUploadViewModel as a parameter.

```
      public ActionResult Upload(ImageUploadViewModel model) {
        var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();

        if (image != null) {
            if (image.Width > 500) {
                image.Resize(500, ((500 * image.Height) / image.Width));
            }

            var filename = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
            image.Save(Path.Combine("../Uploads/Images", filename));
            filename = Path.Combine("~/Uploads/Images", filename);
           
                model.ImageUrl = Url.Content(filename);
                model.ImageAltText = image.FileName.Substring(0, image.FileName.Length - 4);
           
        }

        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

My view for the uploading of images is simple, it has an Html.BeginForm, which handles the Post form method and has the encoding type set to be "multipart/form-data".

Then using The Microsoft.Web.Helpers.FileUpload helper, I request an image from the HTTP post and then display it using a custom DisplayFor template, called ImageViewer.

```
 @model MvcImageUpload.Models.ImageUploadViewModel
    @using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
     }

    <h2>Image Uploader</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
        new { @encType = "multipart/form-data" })) {           
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles: 1, allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false, 
            includeFormTag: false, addText: "Add Files", uploadText: "Upload File") <br />        
                                      
        <input type="submit" name="submit" 
               value="Upload Image" text="Upload Images" 
               style="font-size: .9em;" />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x, "ImageViewer")<br />
    }
```

Here is what the custom DisplayTemplate looks like

```
    @model MvcImageUpload.Models.ImageUploadViewModel
@if (Model != null) { 
    <h4 style="color:Green;">Upload Success!</h4>           
    <p>
        Alt Text has been set to <strong>@Model.ImageAltText</strong>
    </p>
    <img  style="padding: 20px;" 
        src="@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImageUrl) ? "" : Model.ImageUrl)" 
            id="uploadedImage"  alt="@Model.ImageAltText"/>
}
```

This all works and the image gets successfully uploaded to the /Uploads/Images/FileName.extension on the form post.

## My question

How can I now have another view to display all the images in that directory, paged and be able to select and delete and image, from the view and the directory?

Also I know the Microsoft.Web.Helpers.FileUpload, supports uploading of multiple files, but I can't find how to implement this with my current solution. Any help would be greatly appriceated.

Answer (score 3):

After you click the Upload Image button, the system should call method which uses `Request`  to get the file.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        if(Request.Files != null && Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    var postFile = request.Files[i];
                    if (postFile != null && postFile.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        if (postFile.ContentLength < GetMaxRequestLength())  //10MB
                        {
                             var file = new ContractAttachment
                            {
                                Name = Path.GetFileName(postFile.FileName),
                                ContentType = postFile.ContentType,
                                FileLength = postFile.ContentLength,
                                FileData = GetStreamBuffer(postFile)
                            };
                            files.Add(file);
                        }

                    }
                }
          }

    }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

what you are asking about looks rather implementation to me then any query....

to Display:
Fetch all images from your Uploads/Images directory through DirectoryInfo... you can search a directory based on some extension and then it will give you a result set which you can iterate.....

Create a view that will display all records as Image links and in controller fetch the resultset to that View.... Bind those records as you want them to display in your VIEW...

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("your directory path");
               var filesinfo= info.GetFiles("*.jpg", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
               var filenum= filesinfo.GetEnumerator();
               while (filenum.MoveNext())
               {
                   //populate some entity like in your case you have ImageUploadViewModel
               }
```

and you can implement you delete logic using Ajax or through post back depends how you want it....

[Asp.net MVC Views](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-views&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro) following this tutorial and it will let you go through this....

but again what you are asking is more like implementation Code not any issue....

Comment: The issue is I'm not sure how to go about the implementation.

Comment: Also I posted this to help anyone else who might need to know how to upload files using mvc 3.

Comment: i have updaed my answer and added a link to some basic tutorials that will assist you in creating this....

Answer (score 0):

The approach I've followed previously, is to persist the file information in a database(or whatever is appropriate). e.g. path, filename, content-type, filesize.
This gives you the most flexibility when editing (alt text, title, description, relation to other objects). 
Downloading/Viewing the files can then be handled based on path convention, by creating a ViewImage controller which just gets an image id as parameter. 
You can then build a url from the path to the file and you only need to set the content-type.
IIS then does the rest.